# IValidatableObject not validating if child collection is Invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-validation

I have an View Model that is an `IValidatableObject` that contains a collection of `CustomFields` that are also `IValidatableObject`. Both the view model and the custom fields have custom logic to check if they are valid when posted.

The View Model looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public bool IsInspected { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InspectedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<CustomField> CustomFields { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (IsInspected == true && InspectedDate == null)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Inspection Date is required if Inspected.", new[] { nameof(InspectedDate) });
        }
    }
}

public class CustomField : IValidatableObject
{
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (IsRequired && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult($"The {DisplayName} field is required.", new[] { nameof(Value) });
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly validates the `CustomFields`, but it doesn't validate the `ViewModel` itself unless the `CustomFields` have no errors. This means if the user posts invalid Custom Fields and invalid View Model fields, they aren't given notification of the View Model fields until they correct the Custom Fields, post again, and then get the View Model fields validated.

I tried removing `IValidatableObject` from `CustomField` and instead doing a `foreach` loop inside the `ViewModel.Validate()` method, but that didn't correctly assign `ModelState` Keys that highlight the input fields on the form. For example the method shown above creates a `ModelState` Key of `CustomFields[0].Value` while doing a loop inside `ViewModel` just creates a Key of `Value`.

Comment: That is by design. What you should be doing is using validation attributes applied to your view model properties, which also has the added benefit of giving you client side validation as well

Comment: @StephenMuecke Declarative (attribute-based) validation is not expressive enough for scenarios like the OP's. There is currently no way to express the OP's required validation logic using only built-in attributes and writing a new custom validation attribute for each scenario is not ideal either.